# Can't ping IPv4 through Wireless Access Point repeater (while pinging IPv6 works)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6, ipv4

I have this setup and problem:

MAIN ROUTER  | ----------> | Second router (acts as an access point repeater/extender)
Can ping IPv4 -  | ............... | **Can't ping IPv4**
Can ping IPv6 -  | ............... | Can ping IPv6

The problem manifests itself in a weird way in usage, popular sites like Google, YouTube or Facebook work, but most of the smaller sites time out when loading. Through pinging different sites I realized that when connected to the AP repeater I can ping IPv6 but not IPv4.

The repeater is a **Tenda AC1200** and was setup as instructed to be an AP.

Unforunately currently I have no ethernet cable available in order to connect to the AP and make any changes, but maybe it can be fixed without changing AP settings or I can get a cable and fix it if I know the solution.

The problem happens on all devices (laptop, smartphones), so it is not necessarily a configuration problem on my device, it's something that happens by default.

**LE:** I managed to connect to the AP by running `arp -a` while being connected to the AP SSID Wifi. The IP was `192.168.1.4`.

**LE2:** What is more weird: after a while, while being connected to the AP IPv4 starts working (on either 5GHz or 2.4GHz, but not both) for a while and then it breaks again. I disabled 5GHz for now to further pin-point the problem.

**LE3:** It looks IPv4 works a few minutes after a device connects to the AP, after which it stops working (while IPv6 always works as expected).

What I experience while connected to the extender/AP:
(Sometimes instead of "Request timed out" it says that the address 192.168.1.1 aka the gateway, is unavailable, probably because it is IPv4).

[image]

While connected directly to the main router everything works as expected.

This is how the AP is setup:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears the access point may be on a different IP Subnet than the main network. Hook up by Ethernet (move the access point if need be) and check the LAN settings of the access point

Comment: Are you able to ping the main router, and does it show up as the computer's "default gateway"?

Comment: @user1686 I don't seem to be able to wirelessy connect directly to APs admin panel, if I try to access the router IP I just see the login page from the main router (like it forwards what the main router says). I am able to distinguish between the networks (routers) because they have different SSIDs. Connecting to either main router or AP I see that the default gateway is the same (192.168.1.1).

Comment: Well yeah, that's pretty much how an access point is _supposed_ to behave – it just bridges the two sides. (For that reason the AP normally should have a different IP address from the router.) Can you check whether `arp -a` also reports the same MAC for the gateway in both cases? And can you clarify exactly what you meant by "AP-repeater" – do you mean it's connected to the router via Ethernet, or is it connected via WiFi?

Comment: I actually was able to connect to the AP wirelessly (did `arp -a` while connect to the AP SSID and noticed this IP `192.168.1.4`, I accessed it and it's the AP!). I now have access to the AP admin page. *(funny thing: I can post comments while on the AP but not edit my post on SuperUser, I assume editing post is done to an IPv6 server but comments are added to an IPv4 server :D )*

Comment: @user1686 See my new images. The AP is connect to main router via ethernet cable, and it further shares the internet to devices via WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this will work for you..

If the tenda router is connected with ether you can use access point mode.

If the router is connected as wireless repeating function there is 2 option 1.WISP and 2. client Ap.

if you connect with WISP it configure the tenda as 2nd router with it's own LAN network are. Or if you connected as Clint ap it will configure as access point and the devices connected to tenda router have the ip assigned by main router (also trun off the dhcp ).

If this is not useful I'm sorry.